# Can't initialise Bit Field in C as global

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I have declared a Bit Field, given below.

```
struct  {
    volatile uint8_t screenflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t logoflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t oledflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t animationflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t clockdialflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t update_screen:1;
    volatile uint8_t BLE_activity:1;
    uint8_t ble_status:1;
} oled_flag;
```

But when I tried to initialize element of Bitfield out of Main() function it shows following errors when compiling.

> ....\Src\main.c(95): warning:  #77-D: this declaration has no storage
>   class or type specifier   oled_flag.screenflag=1;
>   ....\Src\main.c(95): error:  #147: declaration is incompatible with
>   "struct  oled_flag" (declared at line 92)
>   oled_flag.screenflag=1; ....\Src\main.c(95): error:  #65: expected a
>   ";"   oled_flag.screenflag=1; ....\Src\main.c(96): warning:  #77-D:
>   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
>   oled_flag.logoflag=0; ....\Src\main.c(96): error:  #147: declaration
>   is incompatible with "struct  oled_flag" (declared at line
>   95)   oled_flag.logoflag=0; ....\Src\main.c(96): error:  #65:
>   expected a ";"   oled_flag.logoflag=0; ....\Src\main.c(97): warning:
>
> ## 77-D: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier   oled_flag.oledflag=1; ....\Src\main.c(97): error:  #147: declaration
>
> is incompatible with "struct  oled_flag" (declared at line
>   96)   oled_flag.oledflag=1; ....\Src\main.c(97): error:  #65:
>   expected a ";"   oled_flag.oledflag=1; ....\Src\main.c(98): warning:
>
> ## 77-D: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier   oled_flag.animationflag=0; ....\Src\main.c(98): error:  #147:
>
> declaration is incompatible with "struct  oled_flag"
>   (declared at line 97)   oled_flag.animationflag=0;
>   ....\Src\main.c(98): error:  #65: expected a ";"
>   oled_flag.animationflag=0; ....\Src\main.c(99): warning:  #77-D: this
>   declaration has no storage class or type specifier
>   oled_flag.clockdialflag=1; ....\Src\main.c(99): error:  #147:
>   declaration is incompatible with "struct  oled_flag"
>   (declared at line 98)   oled_flag.clockdialflag=1;
>   ....\Src\main.c(99): error:  #65: expected a ";"
>   oled_flag.clockdialflag=1; ....\Src\main.c(100): warning:  #77-D:
>   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

etc..

The initialization code is:

```
oled_flag.screenflag=1;
oled_flag.logoflag=0;
oled_flag.oledflag=1;
oled_flag.animationflag=0;
oled_flag.clockdialflag=1;
oled_flag.update_screen=0;
oled_flag.BLE_activity=0;
oled_flag.ble_status=1;
```

But when I initialize elements of bit field inside Main() function, It works fine.

Comment: `A member that DOES NOT  represent a bit field can be of any data type and can have the volatile or const qualifier`

Comment: So what is actually 'oled_flag' ?

Comment: Following  up comment#1 I wonder, why your compiler didn't complain about this? Or is it smart enough to neglect it?

Comment: This code compiled successfully when I replace that initialization part to inside main function !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have statements outside a function in C. You need to move the statements inside a function or initialize the global variable together with its declaration:

```
struct  {
    volatile uint8_t screenflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t logoflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t oledflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t animationflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t clockdialflag:1;
    volatile uint8_t update_screen:1;
    volatile uint8_t BLE_activity:1;
    uint8_t ble_status:1;
} oled_flag = {
    .screenflag = 1,
    .logoflag = 0,
    .oledflag = 1,
    .animationflag = 0,
    .clockdialflag = 1,
    .update_screen = 0,
    .BLE_activity = 0,
    .ble_status = 1
};
```

Comment: Am I correct in understanding this is the initialization method of the latest C standard? Would the initialization in older versions be `{1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1}`? (Just curious.)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the designated initializers I used are available since C99 (the latest C standard is C11). In versions before C99 you would indeed have to use the syntax from your comment.

Comment: Thanks, compiled. It is a new info to me. I thought the elements of bitfeild can be initialized just like how variables with inbuilt datatype are initialized.

Comment: It the same rule is applicable to Structures?

Answer (score 2):

Another method of doing this would be to put your bit field struct into a union like this:

```
union {
  volatile uint8_t byte;
  struct {
     volatile uint8_t screenflag:1;
     volatile uint8_t logoflag:1;
     volatile uint8_t oledflag:1;
     volatile uint8_t animationflag:1;
     volatile uint8_t clockdialflag:1;
     volatile uint8_t update_screen:1;
     volatile uint8_t BLE_activity:1;
     uint8_t ble_status:1;
   }bit_field
}oled_flag;
```

Now with the union you can manually initialize the value outside your main function with `oled_flag.byte = {0x95}`. You can still access your bits with `oled_flag.bit_field.screenflag = ...`

Comment: Isn't that highly non-portable?